# Is there a way to access the variable inside the onclick event?

Tags: javascript

I have this simple onclick eventfunction and i would like to know if it's possible to acces the variable that is inside it and use it outside this function, if not is there a way to do something similar?

```js
document.querySelector('.check-parent').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var a = 'abc';
    return a;
});
        
console.log(a);
```

P.S.

In my homepage code i have 3 forms, each form has one id and it needs to display errors in case the fields are not completed properly. And when i click submit i get the parent id and that id goes in a switch function and determins with form it was and what errors needs to display

Comment: That wouldn't work anyway, because the event listener is asynchronous. What *exactly* are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: you can declare variable outside this function and access anywhere you want

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Comment: i tryed to define it outside and then acces it inside but i need the result of the click event. I have on my homepage 3 contact forms and to display messages under each field in case of an error i need to know what id the parent has, when i know that i will display the correct errors

Comment: If you want to access data *inside* the click handler, put the code *inside*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to get a few things correct:

1. The this variable changes inside the callback since the scope changes. 
   Hence bind outer this to your clickhandler(**bind(this)** in below snippet)
2. console.log(a) would not print undefined since it's again in different scope.
   You'll have to trigger this call only after a click event is performed. Hence wrap it in a function & call this from the handler by passing the value.(**this.fromClick(innerVariable)** in below snippet)

Below's a sample snippet([ES5 demo](https://codepen.io/knomdlo/pen/WXxPRV) & [ES6 demo](https://codepen.io/knomdlo/pen/eezxWd)):

```
this.count =0;

document.getElementById('myButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
//Access outer variables
this.count++;
document.getElementById('buttonCount').innerHTML = this.count;

//Send something outside 
var innerVariable = 'String from  click handler!!';
this.fromClick(innerVariable);

}.bind(this));

this.fromClick = function (innerVariable) {
 alert(innerVariable);
}
```